# How to repeat 1-9 with for loop?

Tags: c, for-loop

This is my code so far. The output that my code produces is this:

```
12345678901112131415161718190212223242526272829031323333435
```

I'm looking to get the following output:

```
12345678901234567890123456789012345
```

I tried using `for` loop but it's not giving the right output.

```c
for (i = 1; i <= 35; i++)
{
    if (i % 10 == 0)
    {
        printf("0");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%d",i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The last print statement will print values > 9 (1, ..., 9, 0, 11, 12 ... 19, 0, 21, 22 ...).  Here is one solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    for (int i = 1; i < 36; i++) {
        printf("%d", i % 10);
    }
}
```